# How do I access cpanel?

Tags: magento, cpanel

How do I access cpanel?
I have made backups but for the tgz file and when I try to open or save them I get the HTTP ERROR 500 error message that the website cannot handle the request.

Answer (score 0):

500 means there is an 'internal server error'.

It is very general.

If you turn real error reporting / logging on, you can see the error behind the 500.

Check error log: (linux command on server)

```
tail -n 200 /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log
```

OR

```
 tail -n 200 /usr/local/cpanel/logs/error_log
```

for cpanel error logs

OR Turn on PHP error reporting: (in the index.php file or another file that gets executed)

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

OR In php.ini file set:

```
display_errors = on
```

OR in .htaccess file:

```
php_flag display_errors 1
```

OR Check file permissions on the public_html folder

Hope any of that helps